# Why won't jQuery on click Event receive an Object.method?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to trigger a method with jQuery's click Event. I want to use the Object.method directly, but it only works when I wrap it in a function. Why?

Example Working Code:

```
function play () { a.play(); }
a = new Audio("http://music-ringtone.com/ringtones/04/music-ringtone-com-Live%20to%20Win_68_04.mp3");
$("#my-button").click(play);
```

Example Non-Working Code:

```
a = new Audio("http://music-ringtone.com/ringtones/04/music-ringtone-com-Live%20to%20Win_68_04.mp3");
$("#my-button").click(a.play);
```

Comment: Because without the function you don't have an event listener handler, you've only a clicker.

Comment: Try `$("#my-button").click(a.play.bind(a));`